# Javascript operating on html that might not exist yet

Tags: javascript, delegates

I found some code that I'd like to use [on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dL0hb3ar/8/)

```
var tags = [].slice.call(document.querySelector('.tagcloud')
.getElementsByTagName('a'));

tags.forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
}); 

function randomColor() {
    return  '#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) *     0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6);
});
```

but I inserted it in my shopping cart's platform (in the area they give me fr JS) and I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

The code is fairly straight forward and obviously works on fiddle, so I suspect perhaps its because the relevant html isn't generated yet?  I think this has to do with "delegating", but I'm unclear on how to implement.

here is the generated HTML:

```
<div class="footer_block_content tagcloud">
    <a class="tag_level2 first_item"> asd </a>
    <a class="tag_level1 item"> rfds </a>
    <a class="tag_level1 item"> ewsf </a>
    <a class="tag_level3 item"> sdfa</a>
    <a class="tag_level1 item"> earf </a>
    <a class="tag_level1 item"> sdfae </a>
    <a class="tag_level1 last_item"> adfa </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your putting these code in , as browser render by order, and execute the codes it see imediately, the `<a>` may not rendered at that time. 
You can wrap the scripts into a function, and assign that function to window.onload, as jsfiddle do:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var tags = [].slice.call(document.querySelector('.tagcloud')
    .getElementsByTagName('a'));

    tags.forEach(function(el) {
      el.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
    }); 

    function randomColor() {
        return  '#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6);
    };
};
```

Addition Note, you put a `')'` at the end of `randomColor`, it'll cause a syntax error if its not a typo.

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
  var tags = [].slice.call(document.querySelector('.tagcloud')
    .getElementsByTagName('a'));

  tags.forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
  }); 

  function randomColor() {
      return  '#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) *     0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6);
  };
}
</script>

<div class="tagcloud">
<a href="#" class="tag-link-79">tag1</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-78">tag2</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-35">tag3</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-32">tag4</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-29">tag5</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-30">tag6</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-34">tag7</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-31">tag8</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag-link-33">tag9</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi check if is this what you want to do:

```
    <div class="tagcloud">
    <a href="#" class="tag-link-79">tag1</a> 
    <a href="#" class="tag-link-78">tag2</a> 
    <a href="#" class="tag-link-35">tag3</a> 
    <a href="#" class="tag-link-32">tag4</a> 
    <a href="#" class="tag-link-29">tag5</a> 
    <a href="#" class="tag-link-30">tag6</a> 
    <a href="#" class="tag-link-34">tag7</a> 
    <a href="#" class="tag-link-31">tag8</a> 
    <a href="#" class="tag-link-33">tag9</a> 
    </div>

<script>
    function addColors(){
        var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

        for(var i=0;i<tags.length;i++){
            tags[i].style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
        }
    }

    function randomColor() {
        return  '#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6);
    }

    document.load = addColors();
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dL0hb3ar/8/

Comment: Well, yeah... it is.  That's why I linked to that exact jsfiddle page in my question :)

Comment: To ensure that the html is fully loaded before execute the script put your function on load like this document.load = addColors();

Comment: Ahh, OK... sorry I misunderstood.  OK, I tried that and I no longer get the error (yay!) but I don't get any colors either.  I might have something wrong so I'll play with it.  You got me past the error anyway! THanks

Comment: I did use it, and no color change.  I'm investigating

Comment: check if you are adding another line like document.load = addColors(); because if you do you are overwriting the previous one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83304/discussion-between-bcsteeve-and-marco-mendao).